# maliit keyboard - black box on letters

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I've managed to install `maliit-server` and keyboard plugins from [github](https://github.com/maliit). I run the server and then the example like this

```
export QT_IM_MODULE=Maliit
maliit-server -software &
maliit-exampleapp-plainqt
```

Keyboard shows up as expected, but there appears a black box in the center of the keyboard. I don't know / couldn't find where this box is coming from.

[image: Maliit keyboard - black box]

I'm using `Xubuntu (14.04 LTS)`, `Qt 5.5`. Anyone have experienced this problem?

Comment: How does this issue relate to QML?

Comment: bacause the keyboard is implemented in `QML`, I think.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get a black box, it works ok in mint. I am also trying to get maliit keyboard working on windows though, and there I get an invisible box right about the same spot as your black box. What I mean by that is that the keys don't react to the mouse pointer in that area. Weird :s

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu Unity as well. Same issue.. black box... completely lost.

Answer (score 2):

That is probably the QQuickView of the extended keyboard panel [maliit-keyboard-extended.qml](https://github.com/maliit/plugins/blob/master/maliit-keyboard/qml/maliit-keyboard-extended.qml). The window handling code seems to be quite buggy (see [inputmethod.cpp](https://github.com/maliit/plugins/blob/master/maliit-keyboard/plugin/inputmethod.cpp)).

Note that this code was written for some specific platform (some years ago) and probably needs adaption for other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

The black box is the extended keyboard panel. For some reason it's a square before it has been used (its purpose is to show additional special characters when holding for a second on fx the A key).

It should be transparent, but it seems transparency is not working for you as the keyboard itself should have a semi transparent background, not black.

However transparency is not the real issue, as transparency was working for me but the extended panel was still blocking input. At first it seemed to not be a problem on Linux Mint, but that is simply because it was placed somewhere else. Still blocks mouse input in that area, just happens to not be on the keyboard.

On windows I have fixed the problem by adding:

```
view->show();
view->hide();
```

to:

```
QQuickView *getOverlaySurface (MAbstractInputMethodHost *host, QQuickView *parent)
{
    QScopedPointer<QQuickView> view(new myQQuickView (0));

    view->setTransientParent(parent);

    host->registerWindow (view.data(), Maliit::PositionOverlay);

    makeQuickViewTransparent(view.data());

    // Overlays should be hidden from the start, otherwise it may block 
    // underlying surface despite the overlay being empty. For hide() to work 
    // it needs to be shown first. 
    view->show();
    view->hide();

    return view.take ();
}
```

in [inputmethod.cpp](https://github.com/maliit/plugins/blob/master/maliit-keyboard/plugin/inputmethod.cpp)

This only works on windows though. On Linux Mint it doesn't work and also causes transparency to fail.

Comment: Thanks for the update. We need this for Linux and have instead implemented our keyboard using platform input context plugin. This might be needed for furture inegration.